# How to issue SSL certificate with SAN extension?

Tags: openssl

I have a pair of Root CA keys. How to issue a new SSL certificate with SAN (Subject Alternative Name) extension? I tried this

```
openssl genrsa -out ssl.key 2048
openssl req -new -config ssl.conf -key ssl.key -out ssl.csr
openssl x509 -req -sha256 -days 3650 -CAcreateserial -CAkey root.key -CA root.crt -in ssl.csr -out ssl.crt
```

ssl.conf:

```
[req]
prompt = no
distinguished_name = req_distinguished_name
x509_extensions = v3_ca

[req_distinguished_name]
CN = 127.0.0.1

[v3_ca]
subjectAltName = @alt_names

[alt_names]
IP.1 = 127.0.0.1
IP.2 = ::1
DNS.1 = localhost
```

but generated certificate didn't contain SAN.

However, self-signed certificate produced by the command below contains SAN:

```
openssl req -new -x509 -sha256 -days 3650 -config ssl.conf -key ssl.key -out ssl.crt
```

Comment: Another approach is to use `-extfile` and if sectioned `-extensions` **on `x509 -req`** to add SAN or other extensions to the cert **without** (instead of) putting them in the CSR. Though this may be less convenient if you want to reuse the CSR.

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 thank you. That's what I need. Don't be shy to create an answer. I'll accept it.

Comment: Can you adjust the title, it is not related to CA keys: How to generate SSL certificate having SAN entries?

Comment: @eckes, adjusted.

Comment: In the end, I found an example of how it's done [here](https://mta.openssl.org/pipermail/openssl-users/2016-January/002764.html).

Answer (score 3):

1. My CSR didn't contain SAN. Extensions should be specified in `req_extensions` instead of `x509_extensions`.
2. There is [a bug](https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.1.0/apps/x509.html#BUGS) in `x509` command:

   > Extensions in certificates are not transferred to certificate requests and vice versa.

So I solved my problem with `ca` command:

1. Created empty `ca/newcerts` folder and empty `ca/index.txt` file.
2. Edited `ssl.conf`:

   ```
   [ca]
   default_ca = CA_default

   [CA_default]
   dir = ./ca
   database = $dir/index.txt
   new_certs_dir = $dir/newcerts
   serial = $dir/serial
   private_key = ./root.key
   certificate = ./root.crt
   default_days = 3650
   default_md = sha256
   policy = policy_anything
   copy_extensions = copyall

   [policy_anything]
   countryName = optional
   stateOrProvinceName = optional
   localityName = optional
   organizationName = optional
   organizationalUnitName = optional
   commonName = supplied
   emailAddress = optional

   [req]
   prompt = no
   distinguished_name = req_distinguished_name
   req_extensions = v3_ca

   [req_distinguished_name]
   CN = 127.0.0.1

   [v3_ca]
   subjectAltName = @alt_names

   [alt_names]
   IP.1 = 127.0.0.1
   IP.2 = ::1
   DNS.1 = localhost
   ```
3. Ran commands:

   ```
   openssl genrsa -out ssl.key 2048
   openssl req -new -config ssl.conf -key ssl.key -out ssl.csr
   openssl ca -config ssl.conf -create_serial -batch -in ssl.csr -out ssl.crt
   ```

Comment: Is there an easy way to generate the config from the csr?